# How much energy is required to liquify oxygen?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase, chemical-engineering, liquids, ideal-gas

Does anyone know where I can find some documentation of a real-world liquification process, and the energy costs?

I can calculate the heat that must be removed from O2 gas to get to liquid, but how would this translate to an electricity cost for cooling equipment?

Comment: What is the efficiency of your chiller?

Comment: Can I assume some arbitrary value just to see how the calculation works?